# Trying to install ubuntu while keeping partner's files

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

Been working on this all morning, would love some help! for context, and it may be overexplained: My partner's screen hinge broke, so we have to use a backup. The backup now has all the important files, but now will not go past windows boot up; Installing ubuntu because it's better anyways and actually runs, but I want to keep the files. Now I'm at the partitions section of installation type

tldr; dont know how to work partitions, cant boot laptop to fix in windows, would like to keep files

[partitions look like this](https://m.imgur.com/a/6ZPXMxp)

Comment: K - Do you really have all the files backed up?  I would make another copy to be sure, assuming that you have or can afford a USB device large enough to handle everything.  You can use the Ubuntu installation USB to copy the files out of your computer and onto a backup device, and then let Ubuntu wipe your hard drive clean and install.

Comment: *dont know how to work partitions* so better to **stop right NOW** before you do something you'll regret. Backups are essential exactly because hardware fails and it did. If you or your wife had proper backups all of this would be irrelevant. But you don't so you need to think carefully about your next steps and such steps should NOT include installing anything else on that drive and risk loosing the data forever. You can use the Ubuntu live session NOT to install but to COPY everything you need OUT of that drive.

Comment: I think I'll ask about the old laptop's files; if it has everything i will definitely just wipe the computer entirely with fresh ubuntu; have not touched partitions at all since I was hoping for help; If there are files missing (they will be on the new laptop) What should I do, just deal with the loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you definitive advice without knowing a bit more, but I'm assuming it's a laptop (hence hinge broken!), and that the backup is on the same hard drive as the Windows installation. If it's in fact an external USB backup drive then it's much simpler, but if it's internal and on the same drive as Windows, I suggest that - as someone who doesn't know much about partitions etc. - you will find it easiest to open a live USB session of Ubuntu, then copy your files from the backup (or you may even find the originals are accessible) to a second external drive.

I'm not sure how far you got ... it looks like you may have tried to install already, so you may have an Ubuntu iso USB already but instructions below if not.

(1) You will need a Ubuntu installation USB ISO - if you don't have that already you'll need to get access to a working computer and a USB stick with at least 4GB capacity. Anything on that USB will be deleted in the process. Go to https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop to download the file, and go to https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview to see simple instructions for how to do it.

(2) You then go to your unbootable computer, put the USB in and turn it on and hit one of the keys that allows you to enter the boot menu. Different manufacturers use different keys to do this - it's likely to be one of f2 / F10 / f12 / Esc / Del. The correct button to press will likely flash on the screen very briefly before it tries to boot up. Once you are in there, you should find a setting allowing you to select boot order. Make sure USB is the first option. Save the changes and exit, then reboot.

(3) If this goes well, you should then get to the Ubuntu installation setup screen where you are offered the options of installation or 'try Ubuntu'. Do **not** choose to install Ubuntu (you risk losing the data you want to keep). If you select 'try Ubuntu', it will open a fully functioning version of ubuntu but do nothing to your hard drive with all the files on it that you want to keep. Once it's fully loaded, you should be able to find your hard drive and locate the things you want to save. You can then copy then to a second USB stick.

(4) Once you've retrieved it all, you can go back to the installer, reformat the whole drive and start again from scratch.

There are undoubtedly better ways to do this, but they carry some risk of data loss if you don't know what you're doing, and I think for someone that is unsure about partitions etc, this is probably a pretty safe thing to try.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you, I was thinking of trying that! Either find it through try ubuntu or restore the old laptop to a state where it has anything, keep files on seperate usb, install ubuntu, then have at it